# My swift code won't execute a vibration

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, vibration

I made an app in xcode that vibrates forever with a button, and stops with a button, but when I test it on my iphone it doesn't vibrate. Help?

```
var timer: Timer?


@IBAction func button1(_ sender: UIButton) {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("doaction")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@IBAction func button2(_ sender: UIButton) {

    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil

}
```

I am also using an iphone 7 plus, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Make sure your mobile vibration is not set to off? It works only when the mobile vibration is turned on.

Comment: how do i turn it on?

Comment: Settings -> Sounds -> there you have to on vibrate

Answer (score 0):

Replace `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` with `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound`. Also, make sure that you are importing `AudioToolbox`.

If you want to use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`, you have to do it as follows

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```